# How do I add/remove IPs based on AWS autoscaling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an ELB pointing to two instances of Varnish. The Varnish servers talk to an app server, and both kinds of servers need to be autoscaled.

This is all set up happily, but for one little detail:

The varnish servers have a list of IPs they are proxying for and will accept purges from, and the app server has a list of the varnish server IPs so it can purge pages from cache.

How do I get this information at the time servers are added or removed and trigger a process? I can write a script to tweak the list of IPs on the varnish and app servers once I have it, it's just hooking and fetching this information that's not obvious.

Or am I completely misunderstanding this problem and there's a simpler approach?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible there is a way to configure it without needing to maintain IP lists. Without knowing more about how your application works its hard to provide advise on that solution.

However, you can configure your autoscaling group to send events upon changes to the autoscaling group. This will be handled via SNS -> SQS.

You will need to build a reader for SQS which will then update your configuration.